# comException is unhandled

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
Public Class Stock
    Dim a As New Module1
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim category, item As String
    Private Sub Stock_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        a.Connect()
        rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.Open("SELECT * FROM Stock", a.cn)'this line show error'
        rs.MoveFirst()
        While rs.EOF <> True
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(rs.Fields("Item_Category").Value)
            rs.MoveNext()
        End While
    End Sub
```

Comment: what is the exception you're getting ? also, what is this "a" ?

Comment: COMException was unhandled.

Comment: The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.